# Save lat & lng values into point field in mysql

Tags: mysql, geospatial, innodb

I have a table with fields latitude and longitude stored as float values, and I want to start saving them into points in a new column to use spatial features.

Currently, I have the values as following

- Example latitude: 41.7298
- Example longitude: -87.5995

If I want to start saving them as points, how should I do this? Do I need to convert them to radians? Degrees? Or what format?
Also, when fetching them, how could I be doing so?
Assume I have a column called "location" as point datatype.
I have an InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN ll_point POINT;
UPDATE t SET ll_point = POINT(lng, lat);   -- Note: LNG first
```

After you have written your code to use `ll_point` instead of `lat` and `lng`, cleanup:

```
ALTER TABLE t DROP COLUMN lat,
              DROP COLUMN lng;
```

Lat/lng are in degrees, just as you have now.

Side note:  there is no comma in

```
GeomFromText('POINT(6.905235 79.862687)')
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html